# How to remove empty value with key in json

Tags: javascript

There is an array as below.

```
const A = [
     { comapany: 'yes' },
     { fruit: 'apple' },
     { id: null }
]
```

And I want to remove if the value is empty.

```
const A = [
     { comapany: 'yes' },
     { fruit: 'apple' }
]
```

How can I remove this? Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` method and get non null values.

```js
const A = [
     { comapany: 'yes' },
     { fruit: 'apple' },
     { id: null }
]

const res = A.filter(x => Object.values(x).filter(y => y).length > 0);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hmm... `const res1 = A.filter(x => A[x]);`

Answer (score 0):

`Delete` the key then then `splice` from array.

```js
const A = [
     { comapany: 'yes' },
     { fruit: 'apple' },
     { id: null }
]

for(var i=0;i<A.length;i++)
{
  var hasValue = false;
  for(var key in A[i])
  {
    if(A[i][key]==null)
      delete A[i][key];
     else
      hasValue = true;
  }
  if(hasValue==false)
  {
    A.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
  }
}

console.log(A);
```